# Save File PDF Pimaco

Tags: laravel, pdf

I'm trying to generate the pdf and download it using a lib based on mpdf.
But I'm trying to output-pdf and don't download it.

The script as standard displays the file in pdf on the page but I need that instead of showing on the page the file is downloaded.

Original file

```
 public function output(string $name = null, string $dest = null)
    {
        $this->pdf->WriteHTML($this->render());
        $this->pdf->Output($name, $dest);
    }
```

Modified File

```
    public function output(string $name = null, string $dest = null)
    {
        $pdf_data = $this->pdf->WriteHTML($this->render());
        $path = '\opt\lampp\htdocs\site\public\comprovantes'.$name.'.pdf';
        $this->pdf->Output('\opt\lampp\htdocs\site\public\comprovantes', $pdf_data);
    }
```

Not Working with this modificated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WORKING With:

```
    public function output(string $name = null, string $dest = null)
    {
        $content = $this->pdf->WriteHTML($this->render());
        $this->pdf->Output('/opt/lampp/htdocs/site/public/comprovantes/filename.pdf', 'F');
    }
```